# Matching proper colors of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm making a very simple minigame which idea is to pick the proper color of the figure you've seen for about a second or two by clicking one of the four divs with the id's circle1, circle2 etc. with the specific colors:

```
var odpowiedz_kolor = $('<div class="label id="gra">Jaki kolor miał następujący kształt?</br></br><ul class="inline">'+
                '<div class="odpowiedz_pojemnik" id="' + wylosowane[losowa_z_wylosowanych_figur].figura + '"> </div></br></br>'+
                '<ul class="inline">'+
                '<li><div class="kolo" id="kolo1"> </div></li>'+
                '<li><div class="kolo" id="kolo2"> </div></li>'+
                '<li><div class="kolo" id="kolo3"> </div></li>'+
                '<li><div class="kolo" id="kolo4"> </div></li>'+
            '</ul></div>');
```

I've cut out the unnecessary code...

```
$('#kolo1').css('background-color', wylosowane[0].kolor);
$('#kolo2').css('background-color', wylosowane[1].kolor);
$('#kolo3').css('background-color', wylosowane[2].kolor);
$('#kolo4').css('background-color', wylosowane[3].kolor);
$(".kolo").on('click', function(){
var color = $('.kolo').find('#kolo').css('background-color');
```

I've set the colors as seen above. Now's the question how to retrieve the according colors 'cause I'm stuck on the click handler. I'd appreciate even the ugly but working solutions.

The scenario is:

- you see 4 different figures with different colors for a couple of seconds
- you now have to decide which one was it (if pick good/bad then...)

[image: example]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What colors do u want to retrieve? can you be more specific?

Comment: One thing I've noticed is in your click statement, you write `find('#kolo')` but you have nothing with an id of `kolo`.  Check what you're doing there.  You have to specify which kolo you're asking about.

Comment: that is `undefined` because your statement `$('.kolo').find('#kolo').css('background-color');` contains `#kolo` which is nowhere to be found...

Comment: the triangle already has the color atribute kept in an array. it's one of those four colors to choose from. how to match those colors when the player chooses the correct/wrong one with the specified id's - #kolo1, #kolo2 etc.? english is not my native.

Comment: Separation of concerns. You would benefit from it. Don't treat your view (element styles) as your model (source of data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to know the color of the figure that you just clicked, so I suggest you made this :

```
$(".kolo").on('click', function(){
    var color = $(this).css('background-color');
}
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/F3HB5/

---

**EDIT :**

Based on your code, I have updated your jsFiddle to this one : http://jsfiddle.net/8LFR7/3/.

There were 2 main errors :

1. when you want to target an id, you have to put a `#` before the id -> `$("#" + wylosowane[losowa_z_wylosowanych_figur].figura).css('background-color')`.
2. As you remove your figure before the test, you have to capture the color BEFORE you remove it and save it in some variable : here I have put it at the beginning of the `setTimeout` block : `var targetColor = $("#" + wylosowane[losowa_z_wylosowanych_figur].figura).css('background-color');`

Comment: It aint it 'cause the class has no 'background-color' attribute, only the id's. And yes, I want to compare the clicked one with the correct one.

Comment: i don't think it matters, if the id has the background or the class..you can access with id or class

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek I know that you defined the colors via the id of the element with class `kolo`, but the elements are the same so you will get the color even with the selector on the className. And if you want to retrieve the color of the triangle, you have to select it with `$(wylosowane[losowa_z_wylosowanych_figur].figura)`.

Comment: so i suppose i screwed somewhere here:
`var losowa_z_wylosowanych_figur = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;`

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek Can you explain a bit more what does not work? I have added a base jsFiddle, but you can modify it in order to adapt to your code...

Comment: the only thing that your missing in your code is the `event` parameter passed in the click function.

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek I have updated your jsFiddle in order to make it work. I have edited my answer with the errors that I have seen (and as pointed out by Hmxa Mughal, `event` is only available on IE, but here I have used the variable `this` instead of `event.target.id`)...

Comment: @SamuelCaillerie brilliant! much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a friendly advice, whichever native language you belong to, please use English for your code.

Now your solution: Well you need to match the background-color for the clicked circle with the triangle, so you can do the following to achieve this:

```
$(".kolo").on('click', function(event){
    var id = event.target.id; // For the id, but that does not matter, you can get it using the class also or this

    if($(id).css('background-color') == $('.odpowiedz_pojemnik').css('background-color')){
      alert('Good!');
    }
    else{
      alert('Bad!');
    }
}
```